# lidR: "Argument is not a LAS object" when using catalog_apply

Tags: r, clip, lidr, point-cloud, normalize

I am using the lidR package to read lidar data (LAZ format), then using `clip_roi()` and `normalize_height()` to process the data for the segment trees function. These functions are being executed within a function (`tree_pos()`) which the `catalog_apply()` tool is using against a `LAScatalog`.

If I dont run the `clip_roi()` tool the process works however since the `clip_roi()` saves data to a `list` not a `LAScatalog` then `normalize_height()` tool flags this error:

> "Argument is not a LAS object". Here is the code:

```r
comp <- readOGR("comps")

tree_pos = function(cluster)
{
  las = readLAS(cluster)
  if (is.empty(las)) return(NULL)
  
  #clip current las with comp boundary
  las<-clip_roi(las,cmp)
  if (is.empty(las)) return(NULL)
  
  #normalize currnet comp
  las <- normalize_height(las, tin())
  
  #extract individual trees
  las<-segment_trees(las,li2012())
  return(las)
}

#use tree_pos function below

for (i in comp$lid) 
{
  cmp<-subset(comp,lid==i)
  plot(cmp)
  cmp<-subset(comp,lid==i)
  cmp<-gBuffer(cmp, byid=TRUE, width=0)
  project <- readLAScatalog("folder")
  crs(cmp) <- crs(project)
  project<-catalog_intersect(project,cmp)
  opt_chunk_buffer(project) <- 15
  opt_chunk_size(project) <- 250
  opt <- list(raster_alignment = 20, stop_early=F)
  output <- catalog_apply(project, tree_pos, .options = opt)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways to achieve what you are trying to do but your code has numerous flaws. So many actually that I can't explain them all. I hope the following code will help you to clarify how it works.

If I want to stay close to your original code it'd **look like** that

```r
tree_pos = function(ctg, cmp)
{
  las <- clip_roi(ctg, cmp)
  if (is.empty(las)) return(NULL)
  las <- normalize_height(las, tin())
  las<-segment_trees(las,li2012())
  return(las)
}

project <- readLAScatalog("folder")

for (i in comp$lid) 
{
  cmp<-subset(comp,lid==i)
  tree_pos(project, cmp)
}
```

If I want to stay close to the design of the package it would **look like** that:

```r
tree_pos = function(cluster)
{
  las <- readLAS(cluster)
  if (is.empty(las)) return(NULL)
  
  las <- normalize_height(las, tin())
  las<-segment_trees(las,li2012())
  return(las)
}

project <- readLAScatalog("folder")

opt_output_file(project) = "folder/plot_{ATTRFROMCOMP}"
ctg_plots = clip_roi(project, comp)

opt_output_file(ctg_plot) = "folder/*_segmented"
opt_independent_file(ctg_plots) = TRUE
ctg_segmented = catalog_apply(ctg_plots, tree_pos)
```

Comment: Thanks JRR, really helped me understand how the package is supposed to work! Have reconfigured to follow the package design.

Comment: The above has been working really well for me. However when I try execute the catalog_apply against my various aoi's the chunks overlap and so it causes the process to fail saying "Data already exists". Any ideas on how to over come this? The aoi's are irregular shapes.